# Projects were not shown in scrapyd

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

I am new to scrapyd,
I have insert the below code into scrapy.cfg file.

```
[settings]
default = uk.settings


[deploy:scrapyd]
url = http://localhost:6800/
project=ukmall

[deploy:scrapyd2]
url = http://scrapyd.mydomain.com/api/scrapyd/
username = john
password = secret
```

If I run below code code

```
$scrapyd-deploy -l
```

I can get

```
scrapyd2             http://scrapyd.mydomain.com/api/scrapyd/

scrapyd              http://localst:6800/
```

To see all available projects

```
scrapyd-deploy -L scrapyd
```

But it shows nothing in my machine?

Ref: http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html#deploying-a-project

If Did

```
 $ scrapy deploy scrapyd2
anandhakumar@MMTPC104:~/ScrapyProject/mall_uk$ scrapy deploy scrapyd2
Packing version 1412322816
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 4, in <module>
    execute()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 142, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 88, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 149, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/commands/deploy.py", line 103, in run
    egg, tmpdir = _build_egg()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/commands/deploy.py", line 228, in _build_egg
    retry_on_eintr(check_call, [sys.executable, 'setup.py', 'clean', '-a', 'bdist_egg', '-d', d], stdout=o, stderr=e)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 276, in retry_on_eintr
    return function(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python', 'setup.py', 'clean', '-a', 'bdist_egg', '-d', '/tmp/scrapydeploy-VLM6W7']' returned non-zero exit status 1
anandhakumar@MMTPC104:~/ScrapyProject/mall_uk$
```

If I do this for another project means it shows.

```
$ scrapy deploy scrapyd
Packing version 1412325181
Deploying to project "project2" in http://localhost:6800/addversion.json
Server response (200):
{"status": "error", "message": "[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'eggs'"}
```

Comment: Have you actually deployed anything to your local scrapyd yet?

Comment: I dont know , Please tell how to deploy

Comment: Am just referring the document and doing the same.(http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html#deploying-a-project).But I have a scrapy project.

Answer (score 0):

You'll only be able to list the spiders that have been deployed. If you haven't deployed anything yet then to deploy your spider you simply use scrapy deploy:

```
scrapy deploy [ <target:project> | -l <target> | -L ]

vagrant@portia:~/takeovertheworld$ scrapy deploy scrapyd2
Packing version 1410145736
Deploying to project "takeovertheworld" in http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6800/addversion.json
Server response (200):
{"status": "ok", "project": "takeovertheworld", "version": "1410145736", "spiders": 1}
```

Verify that the project was installed correctly by accessing the scrapyd API:

```
vagrant@portia:~/takeovertheworld$ curl http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6800/listprojects.json
{"status": "ok", "projects": ["takeovertheworld"]}
```

Comment: This was the error thrown after running the above command    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python', 'setup.py', 'clean', '-a', 'bdist_egg', '-d', '/tmp/scrapydeploy-VLM6W7']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Comment: I need to clean the setup.py and egg right? If yes please tell how to do that?

Comment: Can you post the full trace in your question?

Comment: I had same error, it was because a folder inside my scrapy project had root rights, I deleted the folder and that's it : perhaps check some file permission issue ...

Answer (score 0):

I had same error too. As @hugsbrugs said,because a folder inside the scrapy project had root rights.So, I do that.

> sudo scrapy deploy scrapyd2